# Early memory leak detection on Mac?

Tags: macos, memory-management, memory-leaks

I am looking for ways in which memory leaks could be detected at the time of development something like a dump of leaks on console.

I am not talking about using leaks, shark, instruments. We use them after development. Sometimes finding the leaks after all development is real pain.

Thank you

Comment: What do you consider to be the difference between ‘at the time of development’ and ‘after development’? You can use the tools you’ve listed whilst you’re developing an application.

Comment: By 'at the time of development' of development I mean, activity like, you build your app, do a dry test run or debug, etc.

Comment: And what’s preventing you from using those tools during development?

Comment: I can use those tools, but I am expecting something like #include <crtdbg.h>. Using tools while debugging is not possible and we have to run tool separately. Having such header will avoid most of leaks upfront.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you build your app, you should always also perform "Analyze". It's available just below the build command in the menu if you use Xcode 4. This will catch almost all Objective-C leaks, and shows how an object is leaked as a curvy lines connecting the program texts.

Eliminate all warnings by the analyzer. That will solve 90% of the leak before even running your app.